# Can I display certain Jekyll Data File conditionally?

Tags: jekyll

I have a list of courses to take using this courses.yml

```
- title: Basic Residential HSI Install
  code: OSP0000111
  description: Install and Repair residential and business class POTS, HSI, and Video services
  newhire: true
  skillset: Copper
  jobtype: CST
  advanced: 

- title: PTA Testing Overview
  code: OSP0000114
  description: Teaches the technician how to close out a T1 test using the PTA system
  newhire: false
  skillset: Systems
  jobtype: CO
  advanced: no

- title: Technician Billing 
  code: OSP0000112
  description: Teaches the technician how to properly  bill the customer
  newhire: false
  skillset: Copper
  jobtype: CST
  advanced: yes

- title: Central Office Jumper
  code: OSP0000113
  description: Teaches the technician how to run jumpers
  newhire: true
  skillset: Copper
  jobtype: CO
  advanced: no
```

and I list the courses using:

```
<ul>
{% for teds in site.data.courses %}
  <li>  Course Title: {{ teds.title }} <br />
        Course Code: {{ teds.code}} <br />
       Course Description: {{ teds.description }}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This works just fine.  However, now I want to create a list using the same data file, of only those courses where the newhire variable is "true".

I have not understood any previous document that explains how to do this.  I've tried a where clause and filter to no avail.

Any ideas?

Per https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/ website, I tried adding the where clause:

```
<ul>
{% for new in site.data.courses | where "newhire","true" %}
  <li>  Course Title: {{ new.title }} <br />
        Course Code: {{ new.code }}  |  Job Type: {{ new.jobtype }} <br />
       Description: {{ new.description }} <br />
       <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}schedule.xlsx " target="_blank"> Schedule </a>
       <hr />
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I refreshed the page and nothing happened.  I got the same page, a list of ALL the courses.  No filtering.  I even restarted Jekyll server.  Same result, no filtering.

No errors where noted by the Jekyll server either.

Per your answer, I changed the data file variables.  2ea "0's", 2ea "1's".  Then I changed the html file to:

```
<ul>
{% assign teds = site.data.courses | where: 'newhire', 1 | sort: 'title' %}
{% for teds in courses %}
  <li>  Course Title: {{ teds.title }} <br />
        Course Code: {{ teds.code }} <br />
       Course Description: {{ teds.description }}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The Jekyll server reported no errors but, when I refreshed the page, it displayed none of the data at all.  No list of 4 titles, nor 2 liked I hope, just the web page. :(

UGGH, I saw my error when i reviewed it after dinner :)

Here's what worked:

```
<ul>
{% assign new = site.data.courses | where: 'newhire', 1 | sort: 'title' %}
{% for teds in new %}
  <li>  Course Title: {{ teds.title }} <br />
        Course Code: {{ teds.code }} <br />
       Course Description: {{ teds.description }}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add the code of the failed attempts, and describe the unexpected result or error they produced.

Comment: m69, thanks for taking the time to look into this!   -joe

Answer (score 1):

UGGH, I saw my error when i reviewed it after dinner :)  A clear head helps!

The correct code was:

```
<ul>
{% assign new = site.data.courses | where: 'newhire', 1 | sort: 'title' %}
{% for teds in new %}
  <li>  Course Title: {{ teds.title }} <br />
        Course Code: {{ teds.code }} <br />
       Course Description: {{ teds.description }}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Thank you so much, Christian!!

JOE

Answer (score 0):

I can show you a working example from [my blog](http://christianspecht.de/), where I'm doing something similar like you want to achieve.
**I *think* I tried it with `true/false` in the beginning, but I didn't get it to work, so I used `0/1` instead.**

---

Here's the example:

I have [a data file with projects](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/blog/src/4fbb4f973afefa4d12b34e0654ac1773fea70cc4/src/_data/projects.yml?at=default). Each project has a `sidebar` property which is 0 or 1:

```
- name: Bitbucket Backup
  url: /bitbucket-backup/
  logo: /php/cache/img/bitbucket-backup-logo128x128.png
  desc: A backup tool which clones all your Bitbucket repositories to your local machine
  sidebar: 1
```

In my layout file, I have a sidebar where I only want to list those projects with `sidebar == 1`. [I'm doing this with the following code](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/blog/src/4fbb4f973afefa4d12b34e0654ac1773fea70cc4/src/_layouts/default.html?at=default#default.html-87):

```
{% assign projects = site.data.projects | where: 'sidebar', 1 | sort: 'name' %}
{% for project in projects %}
<li><a href="{{ project.url }}" rel="tooltip" title="{{ project.desc }}">{{ project.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

---

**Please note that it only works for me when I assign the line with the `where` clause to a variable (`projects`) and then loop the variable.**

The following does **not** work:

```
{% for project in site.data.projects | where: 'sidebar', 1 | sort: 'name' %}
<li><a href="{{ project.url }}" rel="tooltip" title="{{ project.desc }}">{{ project.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```